# riscv64-linux-gnu-gdb on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, riscv

I installed the riscv gnu toolchain riscv-gnu-toolchain on Ubuntu 20.04, but no  riscv64-linux-gnu-gdb is found. Does anybody know how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but solved it by using "gdb-multiarch" instead.

sudo apt-get install gdb-multiarch

Comment: Thank you! I ended up compiling from source, as gdb-multiarch gave me the warning message "Architecture rejected target-supplied description." I guess there is something wrong with the Ubuntu package distirbution.

Comment: for those who still can't debug the kernel, you may need to check the warning of gdb-multiarch.

you may need to add-auto-load-safe-path /path/to/the/lab/.gdbinit to /home/<your_username>/.config/gdb/gdbinit